# ARC Welder SDCARD access

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I have an APK that looks to read and write from a specific folder within the /externalstorage/ (sdcard) on an android device.  Is there a way I can direct ARC to a specific folder on my PC?

Thanks for the help;

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the metadata file inside the .CRX file to enable a setting for enableExternalDirectory:

```
"metadata": {
  # Other metadata
  "enableExternalDirectory": true
}
```

Enabling this option means that ARC will prompt you (or your users) for the directory to use for for the external directory, and you can pick a real directory on your system to use. You should then be able to freely read and write files in that directory.

Comment: How does ARC ask? On my system (Linux), if I enable that setting, the app just hangs on launch.

Comment: ARC uses the Chrome fileSystem API (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem). It should be creating a dialog box on startup. We make a call to chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry() to emulate mounting the sdcard path when Android starts up. I'd point you at an example Chrome app which uses it, but I couldn't find one quickly.